# Handling Exceptions in application

Tags: exception

In my application, Need to handle exceptions in two ways:

1. Can be handled by Front desk

   ```
    Try
    {
    //code
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Exception("Contact Admin");
    }
   ```
2. Displaying user friendly exact error message to user that can be handled by users itself.

   ```
    Try
    {

        enter code here

    }
    Catch(Exception ex)
    {

        `code here`

    }
   ```

How to achieve the 2nd way in application?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have seen it previously are the following:

1. To provide an optional list of user messages as part of your response:

Example:

```
MyExtendedObject o = new MyExtendedObject();
try {
    // do your processing
    o.setValue(...);
    return o;
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e);
    o.addErrorMessage("The processing has been unable to complete, please try again");
    // getValue() will be empty for the front-end.
    return o;
}
```

2. If you are in a web application, Return a user-friendly message as part of your http error response